# Как подключать большие background-image?

Tags: css, css3, оптимизация, background

Возник вопрос -Как разработчики решают вопрос с подключением больших фоновых изображений к лендингам? Вот в примере фоновая картинка весом >1мB Если я её просто задам через background-image; пользователь зашедший на сайт каждый раз будет вынужден качать этот мегабайт (допустив кэширование отключино), что ни есть хорошо. И про быструю загрузку данного сайта можно забыть. Если урезать данное фото, а потом сжать, то существенно падает качество (удалось сжать до 200 килобит) Посоветуйте оптимальный вариант, как добавлять большие фото на задний фон одностраничника, но что б не просесть по скорости. 
[image: Большее фото]

Comment: вы так много знаете людей у которых кэширование отключено? делайте в том числе разные картинки под разные размеры экранов.

Comment: под мобильный я вообще планирую background-image убирать и отдавать человеку только цвет с фоном. Но вопрос не об этом

Comment: Ужимайте картинку всеми силами, делайте её меньше тупо по размерам. Потом просто блок сделайте с эффектом блюра и все неровности пропадут.